# Regex with backreference as repetition count

Tags: regex

Is there any way to construct a regex that would work as follows:

> Match integer as group `1`, then match `\1` integers.

This `(\d+)(\s+\d+){\1}` unfortunetly isn't allowed, but I find it a good description of what i am trying to achive.

Comment: what is the language that you're using?

Comment: This is generally extremely not supported. It is probably possible using a [code callout](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic:-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression), but that is a feature some people don't like (you should worry when the Perl RE docs say "A bit of magic"). You might as well write two patterns: Get the number, parse it, and build the second pattern (or run `\s+\d+` `n` times).

Comment: @Kobi This could be an anwer

Comment: Important is what language, what regex motor do you use. Theoretically it is possible like : $text =~ m/(\d+)([\s\d]+)(\g{-1})/mg or m/(\d+)([\s\d]+)(\1)/mg  - this is in perl.  In php this looks like : preg_match('/(\d+)([\s\d]+)(\1)/m', $subject).

Comment: here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/rx2qvrm2/

Comment: @rheese I am interested in solution working in any language. It also seems my bad to not give an example: for string "3 7 6 5 4 3 2 1" i would like to match number 3 and next 3 numbers, so "3 7 6 5". Your answer matches 3 then all numbers and another 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
var numbers = "3 7 6 5 4 3 2 1"; // list of numbers
var iter = numbers.split(" ")[0] // get first number
numbers = numbers.substr(iter.length+1) // chop off first number, and the space that follows it you can comment
var rex = new RegExp("(?:\\d(?: |$)){" + iter + "}","") // create regex
alert((numbers.match(rex)||[]).join("\n")) // a sample alert that joins the array to a string with an element on each line
```

Alternatively, if you want the first digit that defines the number of occurrences in the same array, a few changes make it possible

```
var numbers = "3 7 6 5 4 3 2 1"; // list of numbers
var iter = numbers.split(" ")[0] // get first number
var rex = new RegExp("(?:\\d(?: |$)){" + (+iter+1) + "}","") // create regex
alert((numbers.match(rex)||[]).join("\n")) // a sample alert that joins the array to a string with an element on each line
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kobi for the suggestion to use code callouts. It is indeed possible to build a dynamic length match using the last backreference. The code would look something like this:

```perl
$s = '3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10';
$s =~ /(\d+)\s+((??{"(\\s*\\d+){$^N}"}))/;
print "$1\n$2\n"
```

Prints

```
3
4 5 6
```