# Regex n 1 to 1 matches

Tags: java, regex

Is there a technique using regex to ensure that if there is n ocurrences of a pattern, then there is n occurences of a different pattern elsewhere?

For example... lets just say I have a string that looks like this

```
ppppjksdfjlsdkjfnnnn
pppppjksdfjlsdkjfnnnnn
ppppjksdfjlsdkjfnnn
```

My regex would look something like `p*.*n*`, but I want the first two to match my regex but the last one to not, since in the first and second one, # p's = # n's.

Edit:

Should note that there is no theoretical upper limit on the # of ps and ns, but in practice it would be ~50-100. Also, attempting to put this in a stylechecker, so pure regex is necessary. I understand how you could do this algorithmically.

Also something that might be helpful is that in the application of this, the p's and the n's share an attribute... its more like 
`p(m1)p(m2)p(m3)jfkds(d1)f(m)ljsdn(m1)n(m2)n(m3)`

The closest I have gotten is using a negative lookahead to match when it fails:

`p\((m[0-9])\).*(?!n\(\1\))`

That regex fails when they don't match, but only when the number of `n`'s is less than `p`s. But is also very inefficient and can cause a stack overflow on large inputs.

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the matched pattern in the correct cases

Comment: You could write a function to do that. e.g. check the number of occurrences of pattern `p` and pattern `n`, compare if they are equal, and return true or false. There is no way to achieve that just using regex.

Comment: @Quinn Technically in PCRE flavors and some others it is possible using pure regex but otherwise you're right, a custom method is probably the best idea

Comment: This may be useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728622/regex-with-backreference-as-repetition-count

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to match and return `/(p+)/`, replace `p` with `n` on the returned value, and then use that for your next pattern.

Comment: It looks like you have an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Instead of simplifying the sample data, can you provide actual sample data that you are attempting to pattern match against?

Answer (score 1):

Because this is Java I could see you contructing the Regex via script depending on how complex your source data is. At a simple level the regex would look like this:

`^(p(?!p)(.+?)(?<!n)n|pp(?!p)(.+?)(?<!n)nn|ppp(?!p)(.+?)(?<!n)nnn|pppp(?!p)(.+?)(?<!n)nnnn|ppppp(?!p)(.+?)(?<!n)nnnnn)$`

[image]

Here the regex uses simple alternation to enforce the quanatities of letters you looking for, and requires there to be some non `p` and non `n` in the middle.

You could replace the `(.+?)` constructs with `(.*?)` to allow only leading `p` and trailing `n` with no center substrings.

## Regex Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    pp                       'pp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nn                       'nn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ppp                      'ppp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nnn                      'nnn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    pppp                     'pppp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \5:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nnnn                     'nnnn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ppppp                    'ppppp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      p                        'p'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \6:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .+?                      any character except \n (1 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    nnnnn                    'nnnnn'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: Definitely understand this soln... unfortunately this grows dynamically and has no theoretical upper-bound, but practically the upper bound is ~100. So manually generating the regex is less than ideal.

Comment: Oh I agree, but with the limitations of Java's regex implementation I really don't see a better solution. Unless you script it manually. Sigh... If only they'd implement PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather solve it using a simpler approach like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String input1 = "ppppjksdfjlnnsdkjfnnnn";
    final String input2 = "pppppjksdfppnjlsdkjfnnnnn";
    final String input3 = "ppppjksdfjnlsdkjfnnn";
    System.out.println(input1 + ": " + getAnswer(input1));
    System.out.println(input2 + ": " + getAnswer(input2));
    System.out.println(input3 + ": " + getAnswer(input3));

    }
public static int findAll(String pattern, String input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    int count = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        count = m.group(0).length();
        break;
    }
    return count;
}   
public static boolean getAnswer(String input) {
    int number_p =  findAll("^p*", input);
    int number_n =  findAll("n*$", input);
    return number_p == number_n;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
ppppjksdfjlnnsdkjfnnnn: true
pppppjksdfppnjlsdkjfnnnnn: true
ppppjksdfjnlsdkjfnnn: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is looking to do recursion which is **not** supported in Java flavored Regex.

Usually I see this question posed with balanced open and close parenthesis. If you were using a PCRE flavor then the recursive regex would look like:

```
p((?>[^()]+)|(?R))*n
```